# How to start google extension on tab switch

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have made a simple extension that checks if a URL is on a list. If it is the extension icon changes color for 2 seconds.

I would like it to automatically switch the icon color on tab switch instead of me having to click the extension icon.

This is my current code :

```
var good_urls = \["https://www.google.com/%22,%22https://www.youtube.com"\];
var currentURL

chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'windowId': chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT},
function(tabs){
getCurrentURL(tabs\[0\].url);
updateIcon();
});

function getCurrentURL(tab){
currentURL = tab;
console.log(currentURL);
}

function updateIcon(){

    if(good_urls.indexOf(currentURL) >= 0) {
        console.log("good");
    
        chrome.action.setIcon({path: "icon-on-list.png"});
        console.log("1")
        setTimeout(() => { chrome.action.setIcon({path: "neutral.png"}); }, 1000);
    
    
    }
    else {
        chrome.action.setIcon({path: "icon.png"});
        console.log("3")
        setTimeout(() => { chrome.action.setIcon({path: "neutral.png"}); }, 1000);
    
        
    
    };

}
```

+HTML that activates the script

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="background.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

+Manifest

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Icon Changer",
    "version": "1.0",
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
      },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "activeTab",
        "declarativeContent",
        "storage"
    ],
    "action": {
        "default_icon": "neutral.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

I have no clue how to make the script start automatically.

I am sure its super simple, I am new to making chrome extensions. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Use chrome.tabs.onActivated event listener.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample of chrome.tabs.onActivated.

[image]

manifest.json

```json
{
  "name": "hoge",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  }
}
```

background.js

```js
console.log("background.js");
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener((activeInfo) => {
  chrome.tabs.get(activeInfo.tabId, (tab) => {
    console.log(tab.url);
  });
});
```